# Using Devise before_action :authenticate_user! doesn't do anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to require login on all pages on my Rails 4 web site.
In the ApplicationController I have added `before_action :authenticate_user!`, but it simply doesn't do anything. I have tried to add the same `before_action :authenticate_user!` to another controller, and it works fine.

Do I need to do something else to the ApplicationController, to make the login be required on all actions (Except signup/signin)?

Comment: That should be fine so long as your other controllers actually do inherit from ApplicationController...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's the actual code we use:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   #Actions
   before_action :authenticate_user! #-> routes to the login / signup if not authenticated
end
```

The problem you probably have is two-fold:

--

**Make sure your other controllers are inheriting from `application_controller`:**

```
#app/controllers/other_controller.rb
Class OtherController < ApplicationController 
    ...
end
```

--

**You're somehow "skipping" the `before_action` callback**

If you're using `skip_before_action` anywhere, you need to remove it. It will likely cause a problem with your `authenticate_user!` method. To fix this, I would firstly test without any `skip_before_action` callbacks, and then see what gets it working correctly

---

A further note - `signin / signup` won't matter. They all inherit from the `Devise` controllers; they'll just run as required.

Comment: I just found out that I was using ActionController::Base instead of just inheriting from ApplicationController. I went back to write an answer, but you came before me :)

Comment: lol well thanks for the upvote & acceptance! Is it working now?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED 2019**

In your `routes.rb` file you may have mentioned only **authenticated_user** path like below

```
authenticated :user do
    root to: 'home#index', as: :root_app
  end
```

You should mention **unauthenticated_user** path too to make it work or just **root** path without **unauthenticated_user** or **authenticated_user**