# Tips on Performing Rails User Authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, authorization

I am new to Ruby on Rails development. Currently, I am creating a web app where users can log in, create, and manipulate their own "campaigns" (database objects) that are then displayed on a dashboard. I am using the devise gem, but at best it filters the database objects without actually using any permissions. I need to make sure that the database objects that appear on the dashboard are specific to only the current user that is logged in. What would be a good solution for displaying the campaigns of only the logged in user on the dashboard, and making sure that the user can't access/see anyone else's objects on the dashboard.

Comment: Have you tried [Cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)?

Comment: I have tried cancan, but I don't know if role based authorization would be the best solution. I need to make sure each user has a unique role, and I assume using cancan each user being assigned a new role would be very complex.

Comment: You can have a role that is "I can only see my own posts" without too much work, like where `record.user_id==session_user.id` built into the logic for can or can't show. Other roles might be like "see anything, edit only my own posts" or "see and edit anything"

Comment: You can checkout pundit gem

Comment: It seems like you're over thinking this, from what you're describing there is a relationship between campaigns and users? If so and you're using devise, just do `current_user.campaigns` and use that as the data to populate your web page.

Comment: @ivy_p maybe you could try [gem acts_as_tenant](https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant)

Answer (score 2):

It sound like you need a before_filter on your controller. I don't use devise, but just google ["devise before action"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=devise%20before%20action) and you will find many links [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23855893/using-devise-before-action-authenticate-user-doesnt-do-anything) that might be helpful. On another note, here is an [excellent tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning) that shows how to create your own authentication system. I recommend doing it twice. The [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) are also great.

**Update:**

Try this in your contoller

```
def index
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @campaigns = @user.campaigns.all
end
```

Comment: User authentication is not the problem, authorization is what I am stuck on. If a user is not logged in, he can't see the dashboard at all, yet when he is logged in, he can see the dashboard with his objects and all other objects created by different users.